# Git Push Taking long time on self hosted gitlab server

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

We are using GitLab Community Edition 11.1.4 self-hosted version.
Our current number of the user is 200.
Server configuration is 8GB RAM + 2 core cpu + 8GB SWAP + 400GB Disk Space.
Average code push time for each commit is across 30 seconds.
I tried many solutions but still not able to reduce the push time.
Need suggestions to resolve the issue.

Comment: I take it you've tried a [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)? Will clean up your local repo like unreachable objects or stale working trees.

Comment: yes, I tried this. not get any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server is too soft for 200 users.

As you can read here from gitlab documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html

2 cores is the recommended minimum number of cores and supports up to 100 users...

8GB RAM is the recommended minimum memory size for all installations and supports up to 100 users...

“ You need at least 8GB of addressable memory (RAM + swap) to install and use GitLab! The operating system and any other running applications will also be using memory so keep in mind that you need at least 4GB available before running GitLab.”

Personally, 3 days ago I didn’t read this properly and I tried to install gitlab on a 2 cores CPU / 4GB Ram. I was able to install it but to connect on the first page for initial password setup was like drinking the Atlantic Ocean even if I’m the only person who use Gitlab. I had to change for 4 cores CPU / 8GB RAM and voilà ! Everything is working perfectly.

So check you server’s hardwares. I think you need to scale up. You are too many pushing on it, plus Gitlab is a gourmet...

Best regards